# How long will it take for one of them or both of them?

Tags: contest-math, problem-solving

One knight can storm a castle in 15 days. He and his partner can do it in 10 days. How long does it take the partner to storm the same castle alone?

Pipe A can fill a pool in 5 hours, while pipe B can fill it in four. How long will it take for the two to fill the pool if both are operating at the same time?

I keep getting stuck on questions like these. I am pretty sure I can do the second one by taking the number of liters of the pool as 20. Then we can solve for 5x + 4x = 20. Therefore x = 20/9 hours.

However, I can't seem to work out the first one.

Help would be appreciated.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The knight storms $2$ castles per thirty days and the knight and partner together storm $3$ castles in thirty days. Hence the partner storms $1$ castle in thirty days.

$A$ can fill $4$ pools in twenty minutes and $B$ can fill $5$ pools in twenty minutes. Hence they can fill $9$ pools in twenty minutes together.